# TUG 2016 July 25-27

Tags: tugboat

I know that some of you will give talks at this year TUG to be held July 25-27 in Toronto, Canada. For the first time in my life I am actually couple hours drive from the venue and I am contemplating to attend the conference at least for a day. Unfortunately the conference [web site](https://www.tug.org/tug2016/index.html) is not very illuminating. 
Could one of participants kindly share with me the location of the lectures? I know that most of speakers will stay at

> Bond Place Hotel 65 Dundas St. East Toronto, Ontario M5B 2GB, Canada

but where are the lectures going to be held? In the hotel or at the University of Toronto, or at some other university?

Comment: Well, the Bond Place Hotel has conference rooms, so the talks might might be there. And if you are staying there, then the University of Toronto is only about a 15 minute walk (to the SE edge of the main campus) --- so, there are definitely several hotels much closer by, but it is not unreasonable that the sessions would be held there. Ryerson University is right across the street, however, so that may be a more obvious location.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the comment if you don't know the answer to my question? The question was directed to the small audience of people who are attending the conference (involved with TuG) and are also regulars on this portal. I am pretty familiar with Toronto so you didn't tell me anything I already don't know.

Comment: This question isn't about TeX. Why don't you ask in chat? Or email the organisers?

Comment: However, it seems fairly clear that the conference is taking place in the specified hotel.

Comment: Question about major TeX conference is not about the TeX?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I wouldn't written below in the answer section. Instead, as someone who lives in Toronto, I made a comment: the University of Toronto is, prima facie, a less obvious candidate than the hotel itself or Ryerson. What's with the hostility?

Comment: @PredragPunosevac No as there is no _technical_ aspect to the question: knowledge about TeX won't help writing an answer.

Comment: The conference is as the web site says at the hotel: I'm not sure what is not clear about this. (Business hotels make there money running events and typically have a range of rooms for meetings, talks, _etc_.)

Comment: The web site says "... *Meeting* of the TeX Users Group \\ Bond Place Hotel". This first mention about the hotel is not about accommodation since there's a specific section about accommodations further down the page. So, IMO, the location of the lectures will be one/more of these meeting rooms: http://www.bondplace.ca/meeting-rooms/